# USB devices are not working on server

Tags: 10.04, server, usb

I have installed Ubuntu server 10.04 and my server doesn't detect the external USB devices. Mouse, keyboard and usb harddisk.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure that your USB ports are working: try to connect a mic, or a USB laptop flashlight, or another USB device to ensure they draw power from USB.  Then update your question with the results.